# Женские названия профессий

Tags: грамотная-речь

Почему "учительница" звучит вполне литературно, а вот, например, "парикмахерша" - уже просторечное? Хоть и та, и другая - женские профессии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Парикмахерша - вполне литературно. Не знаю, чем вы руководствуетесь.

Есть, правда, один момент. Суффикс -ш+а наряду с -их+а исторически обозначал не представительницу данной професии (должности, звания и т.п.), а жену представителя оной - офицерша, миллионерша и т.д..  Поэтому иногда возничает ощущение какой-то комичности.

Общих же правил, когда професии имеют нормативный женский вариант названия, нет. Я вот тут недавно списочек составил по спортивным "профессиям" по лексикону комментаторов...
Как вы думаете, какие из данных "профессий" по версии комментаторов имеют женские варианты? 
Вратарь, защитник, полузащитник, нападающий, диагональный, блокирующий, либеро, доигровщик, разырывающий, центровой, квотербек, питчер, лайнсмен, рефери, полусредний, фланговый?

Answer (score 0):

Некорректный вопрос. Что именно Вас интересует?